# Update AWS config with aws-sdk v3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to update the code of my project from aws-sdk version 2 to aws-sdk version 3. I have succeeded to update the different operations with s3 client or sns.

I now face this code (in TypeScript) :

```js
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import * as proxy from 'proxy-agent';

const workWithProxy = (process.env['HTTPS_PROXY']);

export class AWSConfig {

  static readonly region = 'eu-west-1';

  public static setAwsConfig() {
    if (workWithProxy) {
      AWS.config.update({
        httpOptions: {
          agent: <any> proxy(process.env['HTTPS_PROXY']),
        },
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I don't find what could be the equivalent of AWS.config.update with the version 3 of aws-sdk, neither I know how to access this AWS.config (because i need to access to AWS.config.credentials later).

When I see [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/node-configuring-proxies.html) it seems it could be the answer but if I understand correctly, I will have to put the `if (workWithProxy)` everytimes I create a new AWS client like in here : `const sns = new AWS.SNSClient({ region: regionAWS });`

Has someone got an idea of what could I use to re-write this class using aws-sdk version 3 ?